# Date not showing on consecutive posts on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, date

I have a news section that shows posts only with a category of "news". The code is shown below.

The problem is, only the first news post gets a date above it. All the posts following the most recent "news post" don't have dates. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
<div id="news">

            <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=news&posts_per_page=6'); ?>
                <marquee ONMOUSEOVER="this.stop();" ONMOUSEOUT="this.start();" direction="up" scrollamount="2" id="newsMarquee">

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="post">
                        <p class="date"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
                        <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; endif;?>

                </marquee>

        </div><!-- /#news -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed problem.

Had to change the `<?php the_date(); ?>`

to:

```
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
```

Hope that helps anyone out there.

Comment: Really Nice, thanks for answering your own question! Keep doing that!

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto: I do what I can.

Comment: 'the_time' is thousands times better than 'the_date', it work better and it can be used multiple times inside one loop! Thanks for sharing that!